# Swap elements in Matlab as in Python

Tags: matlab, octave, scilab

I am new in Matlab. In Python one can swap elements in a handy way.

> x, y = 5, 10
>
> x, y = y, x

Is there something similar in Matlab (or in Octave/Scilab)?
Otherwise, what is the best way to swap elements without the use of a temp variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) is the function that you're looking for.

```
[y,x] = deal(x,y);
```

**Example:**

```
x=5; y=10;
[y,x] = deal(x,y)

y =
     5

x =    
    10
```